# Is this a geometric set cover problem?

Tags: geometry, optimization

Not sure if this is actually a geometric set cover problem, as the definition I can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem) is quite beyond my level of maths.
I wonder if anyone can help.

Suppose you are given a set of points on a 2D map, and you need to select some of them, where transmitters will be installed.
Each transmitter 'covers' a circular region of radius $r$ around itself.
Consider $r$ fixed.

If a transmitter were installed in each of the points, the whole desired area ($A_0$) would be covered, but there would be significant overlap between the transmitters, with consequent waste of resources.

So the question is: **can one select only some of the points where to install the transmitters, so that the largest possible fraction of $A_0$ is covered, using the minimal number of transmitters?**.

The objective function (to max) could be something like:

$Obj = \frac {A_t}{A_0} \cdot revenue_f - N_{t} \cdot cost_{t}$

where:

- $N_t$ = number of transmitters installed (i.e. of selected points)
- $cost_t$ = cost of one transmitter
- $A_t$ = area covered by the installed transmitters
- $A_0$ = area that would be covered if transmitters were installed in all points
- $revenue_f$ = revenue that would be generated by covering the whole $A_0$ (so we are assuming that covering a given fraction of $A_0$ will generate the corresponding fraction of the revenue)

Here are some illustrative examples of what I described above.

20 points, installing a transmitter in each, shading their coverage areas in transparent red:

[image]

You can clearly see that there is a lot of overlap.

Selecting only the points in blue, shading the union of their coverage area in transparent blue, overlaid with the union of the full coverage area in red:

[image]

This does not do too bad a job, using only 5 out of 20 transmitters, but it leaves a substantial area on the top-right uncovered.
And it does not seem to be an 'optimal' solution: everything else being equal, 15 would have been preferable to 7, as the latter is already in a 'crowded' area.

Intuitively one might think: select one starting point, then select the point farthest from it (so their circles overlap as little as possible), and so on, at each step selecting the point that is farthest from all the currently selected ones, until adding the next point increases the cost without increasing the revenue.
In this sense it wouldn't sound very different from a p-dispersion (maxmin) type of problem.

So, I am trying to understand if this is a known problem, and what type of algorithm could be used to solve it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

To find the area covered by a subset of the circles ($A_t$), one idea could be to sum the areas of the selected circles, and subtract the areas of all their pairwise intersections.
[NOTE: as later commented, this would not work. It looks like the correct formula for the area of the union of $n$ circles is:

$\sum_{k=1}^n {A(C_k)} + \sum_{i=2}^n {(-1)^{i-1} \cdot ( \sum_{s \in S_i} {I(s)} )}$

where:

- $A(C_k)$ is the area of circle $C_k$
- $I$ means 'area of the intersection of'
- $S_i$ is the set of all combinations of $i$ circles one can form from the $n$ selected ones.

So for $n = 2$ the pairwise concept holds:

$\sum_{k=1}^2 {A(C_k)} + \sum_{i=2}^2 {(-1)^{i-1} \cdot ( \sum_{s \in S_i} {I(s)} )} = A(C_1) + A(C_2) - I(C_1,C_2)$

But already for $n = 3$ one would need to calculate and add back in the intersection of all 3 circles (which I don't even know how to find):

$\sum_{k=1}^3 {A(C_k)} + \sum_{i=2}^3 {(-1)^{i-1} \cdot ( \sum_{s \in S_i} {I(s)} )} = A(C_1) + A(C_2) + A(C_3) - I(C_1,C_2) - I(C_1,C_3) - I(C_2,C_3) + I(C_1,C_2,C_3)$

BTW, my notation must be all over the place, apologies for that.
]

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402858/area-of-intersection-between-two-circles) plus some additional calculations, I worked out that the area of the intersection of 2 circles of identical radius $r$ whose centres are separated by a distance $d$ is:

$2 \cdot r^2 \cdot \arccos ({\frac d {2 \cdot r}}) - \frac d 2 \cdot \sqrt {4 \cdot r^2 - d^2}$

So there might be a way to solve this as a binary linear programming problem, although one with a lot of variables and constraints (to code the pairwise intersections), so probably unfeasible when one has anything more than a few dozens points to start with.
[NOTE: and as mentioned above, actually much more complicated than I thought].

---

**EDIT: Following up from RobPratt's suggestion**

Here is my `R` code with the implementation of a set cover problem where the aim is only to cover the initial set of *centres* by the smallest possible number of circles.

```
# Goal: given a set of N points in 2D, select the minimal possible subset of points such that, by drawing a circle of radius r centred in each, all the N points are 'covered' by the circles

# Approach: find which points are within a radius r of each of the initial N points; this constitutes the set of points 'associated' to each point; then select the minimal number of points such that the *union* of their associated points comprises all the N points (set cover)

# 1. User parameters

# Set the total number of points to choose from
N = 20
# Set the radius of the circles to draw (should not be larger than 1)
r = 0.5

# 2. Preparation of the data

# simulate N 2D coordinates
set.seed(91238)
coords <- matrix(runif(2*N), ncol = 2, nrow = N)

# calculate the pairwise Euclidean distance matrix
dm <- as.matrix(dist(coords))
# turn the matrix into a binary contingency matrix by replacing any distances <= r by 1, the rest by 0
dm <- ifelse(dm <= r, 1, 0)

# make the angles for circle drawing
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = 200)

# 3. Plot the initial situation
op = par()
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))

plot(coords, asp = 1, xlim = c(min(coords[,1])-0.5, max(coords[,1])+0.5), ylim = c(min(coords[,2])-0.5, max(coords[,2])+0.5))

for (i in 1:N) {
  CX <- coords[i, 1]
  CY <- coords[i, 2]
  lines(CX + r*cos(theta), CY + r*sin(theta), col = 2, lty = 2)
  #shade("(x-CX)^2 + (y-CY)^2 < r0^2", "red", 0.9, n=200)
}

points(coords)
text(coords, labels = as.character(1:N), pos = 4, cex = 0.7)
title(main = paste0("All (",N,") points selected"))

# 4. Solve by binary linear programming

require(Rsymphony)

obj <- rep(1,N)
dir <- rep(">=",N)
rhs <- rep(1,N)
lp.out <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj, dm, dir, rhs, types = "B", max = FALSE)

sel <- as.numeric(dimnames(dm)[[2]])[as.logical(lp.out$solution)]

# 5. Plot the solution compared with the initial situation

plot(coords, asp = 1, xlim = c(min(coords[,1])-0.5, max(coords[,1])+0.5), ylim = c(min(coords[,2])-0.5, max(coords[,2])+0.5))

for (i in 1:N) {
  CX <- coords[i, 1]
  CY <- coords[i, 2]
  lines(CX + r*cos(theta), CY + r*sin(theta), col = 2, lty = 2)
}

for (i in sel) {
  CX <- coords[i, 1]
  CY <- coords[i, 2]
  lines(CX + r*cos(theta), CY + r*sin(theta), col = "blue", lty = 1)
  #shade("(x-CX)^2 + (y-CY)^2 < r0^2", "blue", 0.9, n=200)
}

text(coords, labels = as.character(1:N), pos = 4, cex = 0.7)
points(coords[sel,], pch = 16, col = "blue")
title(main = paste0("Points ",paste(sel,collapse=",")," selected"))
```

It works, as far as the goal of covering the initial points is concerned, and in this sense I find it a very interesting result, possibly of use in some contexts.
[BTW the code can surely be improved, too; I really went for the easiest path, no attempt to make any elegant or fast implementation].

However, clearly this does not cover anything close to the whole area that would be covered by all the circles, by far:

[image]

If I understood RobPratt's suggestion and content of the post he linked, I would then be supposed to add several more 'auxiliary' points, to 'force' the LP to include more centres, and by doing that, cover the whole area.

This is indeed possible, except that it would indeed be a 'cover the whole area' problem, not 'cover as much area as possible' as in my original formulation; as there would be no measurement of the proportion of points covered, but a set of constraint *forcing* the coverage of the full area.

It is still quite interesting to attempt that nevertheless.

I am just wondering if there is a way to select only a few 'crucial' additional points, e.g. those, in each circle, that are most distant from the centroid of the set of points, to avoid enormously increasing the number of constraints.
Also, if I got this right, since I cannot select any of the $M$ 'auxiliary' points, the constraint matrix would have to be an $(M+N) x N$ matrix(?).

If anyone is (still) following this post and has suggestions or thinks I am barking up the wrong tree, please let me know.

---

**EDIT 2: implementation of the binary LP set cover with auxiliary points**

It seems to work.
The auxiliary points are in red in the plot below. I found them by intersecting each circle with the line by its centre and the centroid, and keeping the intersection farther away from the centroid (in fact now I wonder if I should also keep the one closest to the centroid; or indeed as RobPratt commented, sampling the circumferences; but OK, for further development).
By including these points, the whole area is covered (at least in this example), and this highlights something I find very interesting: some very close centres are selected, because without them some areas would be left uncovered - but that also means that the p-dispersion approach would probably not be effective, as it would first and foremost try and keep the selected centres far apart(!).

[image]

Overall I like this result, so thanks again RobPratt for your input, you helped me think this through and reach what seems to me a rather satisfactory solution!

Comment: The alternating summation formula is an example of the principle of inclusion-exclusion.  Regarding binary linear programming, you might be interested in [my answer to this related post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110592/can-you-irrigate-your-lawn-with-23-sprinklers/110615#110615).

Comment: Thanks! I'll need to think a bit more about this, because I'm tying myself up in knots with the area calculation and all the overlaps, but after looking at the posts you linked, I am now thinking that perhaps I don't need that. Perhaps I only need to impose a condition on the maximal distance between circle centres, i.e. no circle centre must be farther than a given distance from another circle centre. The accepted solution in the post you linked is interesting, but very, very complicated. I would like to think that a simpler formulation might exist.

Comment: Yes, I was specifically referring to my answer, where the candidate centers form a finite set, as in your problem.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. The part that I am still trying to figure out is how a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) relates to a *geometric* set cover problem. For me it is not obvious, sorry. I know how to formulate the set cover problem as a LP with N binary variables, if there are N sets. How a set of points in 2D translates to that is still escaping me at the moment. When I mentioned 'p-dispersion', I meant I *guessed* that choosing well spaced locations would decrease the overlap and increase the chances of covering more of the total area. Just a guess.

Comment: Fix a radius $r$.  Each binary variable corresponds to a circle center, and the covered locations are those that are within distance $r$ of that center.  The set covering constraints are to cover each point, so the variables in a given constraint correspond to the circles that cover that point.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks! Now I understand why you started with a random set of points in the other problem. In the meantime I tried a simple Excel p-dispersion approach, with 23 $(x,y)$ coordinates to find, asking to max the min of the Euclidean distance matrix between them, constraining $\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \le 4$. If the starting $(x,y)$ set is random, the result after several cycles starts resembling the solutions given in the post, BUT I am not sure it covers all the gaps. In fact, if I use the original solution as start (min dist = 1.23), it pushes the points farther apart, to min dist = 1.6 :/

Comment: Aha! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96839/area-of-union-of-n-circles ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636072/find-intersection-point-of-3-circles . So there is a way to write my original problem as an exact binary LP with $N + 2^N-1$ variables. If one were motivated enough, that is :/

Comment: Yes, that seems like a reasonable heuristic to add auxiliary points.  Alternatively, you could uniformly sample from the border of each circle.  Yes, for $N$ candidate circles and $M$ auxiliary points, your constraint matrix will have size $(M+N) \times N$.

Comment: Glad to help.  You can generalize from set cover to partial set cover by introducing binary variable $y_i$ to indicate whether point $i$ is covered, replacing the $\ge 1$ constraints with $\ge y_i$ and then imposing $\sum_i y_i \ge 0.9 (M+N)$ to enforce coverage of 90% of the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cell tower placement problem, and has been pretty well studied by some folks with lots of money to spend on top algorithm designers. Your "intuitively one might think" paragraph is essentially a "greedy algorithm"; various kinds of greedy algorithms can often do OK, but they're seldom optimal.

Anyhow, I'll bet a search for "optimal cell tower placement" along with SODA or FOCS or STOC (the shorthand names for major algorithms/theory of computer science conferences) might yield you several interesting results.

Comment: Thanks! I saw in the meantime that my idea to use the pairwise intersections was quite naive... one would have to use higher order intersections, and then add them or subtract them from the total depending on the total number of locations. So yes, far more complicated than I thought :(

Comment: And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195215/459155) confirms that finding the intersection of more than 2 circles is no trivial matter at all... :( It's incredible how such an apparently simple problem should turn out to be so intractable in exact terms.

Comment: BTW I also ran the advised search. My original problem is not about placing cell towers, I used that example to make it more concrete, but it has to do with something else entirely. So the hits I found, while interesting, go far beyond what I need. But yes, technically I could try and simplify those approaches and use them. Here are some examples: https://gis.smumn.edu/GradProjects/McGregorP.pdf , http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc373/tutNotes/cellTower.pdf , https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1104/1104.2721.pdf , https://ijssst.info/Vol-15/No-3/data/3857a619.pdf